# Run tcpdump in a loop

Tags: bash, tcpdump

I would like to run a script that captures traffic from a server using tcpdump and ping.

I want it to start tcpdump, pause, ping an endpoint, sleep for X number of seconds and then repeat the process. But I want it to start and stop tcpdump between each ping. I thought the code below would work but it jumps out of the loop after a single ping?

Any ideas why this is?

```
#!/bin/bash

#start a process in the background (it happens to be a TCP HTTP sniffer on  the loopback interface, for my apache server):

for i in {1...4}
do
        tcpdump host 8.8.8.8  -ttt &
        sleep 1
        ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8 -c 1

        #.....other commands that send packets to tcpdump.....
        sleep 1
        pkill tcpdump
done
```

Comment: `pgrep` already searches the process listings, no need to pipe the process list into it.  Also, you could just use `pkill` instead

Comment: got this concept from an example, thanks for the pointers I will alter as you suggest

Comment: I still dont understand why it only does a single ping then exits, and dose not loop 4 times though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with your range - you have an extra period there.  So, you are just looping once with the string `{1...4}` instead of `1 2 3 4`.

You could write your code as:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..4}
do
  tcpdump host 8.8.8.8 -ttt &
  sleep 1
  ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8 -c 1
  sleep 1
  kill "$!"                      # kill the background process
done
```

Comment: Strangly even {1..4} does not work, however {1 2 3 4} does?

Comment: Isn't it better to grab the PID right after backgrounding so that the code is resilient to killing an unrelated process - in case we add code to create another background process between the tcpdump and the kill steps?

Comment: @DevilWAH, are you running this with `sh yourscript` by any chance? If so, that ignores the `#!/bin/bash` shebang, so you can't use bash extensions like `{1..4}`.

Comment: @DevilWAH, ...try adding a line like `echo "Running capture $i" >&2`; if it says `Running capture {1..4}`, then you know that brace expansion wasn't honored, which almost certainly means this was run with a baseline-POSIX shell interpreter rather than with bash.

Comment: Tried running it using "sudo bash Scriptname", and yes that worked, seems I had a blank line at top of file so it was not seeing the shebang. Apologies all working now